# Switch and case with lists and arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, switch-statement, case

I have been trying to make a program where the user chooses one option and then I'm using a switch case for every option. My biggest problems are for case 1,2,4.

On case 1: Here I what the user to be able to input as many strings as he/she wants through a list.

on case 2:here I want the user to be able to input 4 strings through an array.

case 3: prints out all the strings from case 1(lists).

case 4: prints out all the strings from case 2(arrays).

case 5: quit program

I know that the code in case 1,2 and 4 is definitely wrong, but I can't seem to find any good answer on what to do, I have been searching the web for quite a while now.

here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryggsäcken
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool running = true;//Ger ett booleskt värde till variabeln     running för att kunna skapa en loop

            while (running)//Här skapas loopen
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till ryggsäcken!");
                Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Lägg till flera föremål i stora facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[2] Lägg till 4 föremål i lilla facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[3] Skriv ut innehållet i stora facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[4] Skriv ut inehållet i lilla facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta");
                Console.Write("\nVälj: ");

                int option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Konverterar från string till Int


                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Lägg till föremål i ryggsäcken: ");
                        List<string> mylist = new List<string> { };
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in 4 föremål");
                        string[] answer = new string[5];
                        for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        break;



                    case 3:
                        foreach (string item in mylist)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                         Console.Writeline(answer[i]);
                         break;

                     case 5:
                        running = false;

                }
            }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to store mylist and answer at the very top level of this function, not in the case(s). Then you need to put checks in cases 3&4 to make sure those values are initialized or have valid info, and then only print the list or answer.

Comment: What is the problem? is the code not compiling? Are you getting a runtime exception? Do you have a specific error message?

Comment: @MatiasCicero Yeah on case 4 i get the error message: System.console does not contain a definition for Writeline

Comment: @ApolloSoftware Do u mean that I should move everything I have regarding mylist and answer to before the while loop? And what do you mean by putting checks in cases 3 and 4. Sorry if I'm slow, just a little new to this.

Comment: @mackanmorre That's because `System.Console` does not contain a definition of `Writeline`. Please, reread the error message, it's actually pretty descriptive. (Hint: Maybe you meant `WriteLine` ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to intialise mylist and answer at the very top level of this class, not in the case(s). Then you need to put checks in cases 3&4 to make sure those values are initialized or have valid info or have more than one element in them, and then only print the list or answer. You can even put a then writeline statement to say "Hey, your variable is not yet initialised or you need to input values." or something to that extent.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryggsäcken
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string> { };
            string[] answer = new string[5];

            bool running = true;//Ger ett booleskt värde till variabeln     running för att kunna skapa en loop

            while (running)//Här skapas loopen
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till ryggsäcken!");
                Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Lägg till flera föremål i stora facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[2] Lägg till 4 föremål i lilla facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[3] Skriv ut innehållet i stora facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[4] Skriv ut inehållet i lilla facket");
                Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta");
                Console.Write("\nVälj: ");

                int option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Konverterar från string till Int


                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Lägg till föremål i ryggsäcken: ");

                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        mylist.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in 4 föremål");

                        for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        break;



                    case 3:
                        if (mylist.Count > 0)
                        foreach (string item in mylist)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                         if (answer.Length > 0)
                        for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(answer[i]);
                        }

                         break;

                     case 5:
                        running = false;
                        break;

                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this now. But i still get 3 error messages.      /Users/marcusnordemar/Desktop/Skärmavbild 2017-04-10 kl. 22.56.00.png

Comment: L in WriteLine needed to be captialised.

Comment: Ok the I have what you said now. The error messages I'm getting are these ones: if (mylist.Length > 0) does not contain a definition for Length. if (answer.Count > 0) operator > cannot be applied to operands of type "method group" and "int". And the last one is: Console.WriteLine(answer[i]); the name "i" does not exist in the current context

Comment: thx, there is no compiling error now. The only problem I have is that when i use option 3 or 4 it doesn't print out anything.

Comment: I moved it outside the while loop and now it works, Thank you!

Comment: @mackanmorre No Problem

Comment: Also don't forget the break after fifth case. Won't compile unless you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the list outside of the while-loop, otherwise it will get deleted after every run.

```
        List<string> mylist = new List<string> ();
        while(running)
        ...
```

In case 1 you should add a loop with an break statement like:

```
case 1:
    Console.Write("Lägg till föremål i ryggsäcken: ");
    while(true)
    {
        string lineEntered = Console.ReadLine();

        //Now here comes the break operator
        if(lineEntered == "stopImDone"){
        break;

        mylist.Add(lineEntered);
    }

    break;
}
```

case 4 should be more like

```
case 4:
    foreach(string i in awnser){
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    break;
    }
```

This way all of the strings entered will be displayed.